# Restful Service in Asp.net fetching information

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

The problem is this code is getting username and password from the whole table like if i enter username of first person and password of second person this code still fetching information but i want to fetch only one user info with same username and password please help me.

```
 [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET","POST")]
    [HttpGet]
    public User Login(string username, string password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            return null;


        var user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email == username);
        var pass = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Password == password);


        if (user == null || pass==null )
            return null;


        return user;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like:

```
public User Login(string username, string password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            return null;


        var user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email == username);
        var pass = user?.Password;


        if (user == null || pass == null)
            return null;

        if (pass != password)
            return null;

        return user;
    }
```

Comment: How would `HttpStatusCodeResult` convert to `User`? recheck your logic

Comment: I thought you would have gone the other way and converted the method to return `IHttpActionResult`

Comment: I should have but didn't want to explain everything that goes with it.

Comment: Ok I can totally relate to what you mean. :)

Comment: Thankyou so much @Nkosi